# Induction proof of Leibniz determinant formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to inductively proof that the denominator of the general solutions of an $n \times n $
system are given by the Leibnitz formula for the determinant
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
    \prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i, \sigma(i)}
.\end{align*}

For the induction step, suppose our matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1, n+1} $ is given by
$( \mathbf{A})_{i, j} = a_{i, j}$. My idea is now to eliminate the first column of the matrix (normal gaussian elimination) and consider
the $(n\times n)$ submatrix $(\mathbf{A})_{1:, 1:} = \widetilde{\mathbf{A}}$ with
\begin{align*}
    (\widetilde{\mathbf{A}})_{i, j}
    = \frac{a_{i+1, j+1}\cdot a_{1, 1}- a_{1, j+1}\cdot a_{i+1, 1}}{a_{1, 1}}
.\end{align*}
To this matrix we can apply the formula we assume to be true, so what I want to show is
\begin{align*}
a_{1, 1}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\widetilde{\mathbf{A}})_{i, \sigma(i)} 
= 
    \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n+1}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
    \prod_{i = 1}^{n+1} a_{i, \sigma(i)}
.\end{align*}
(The additional factor $a_{1, 1}$ comes from the fact that for getting the denominator of the general solution
we have to bring it to the other site and there it will cancel out, but this we don't consider when
applying the formula directly to the submatrix). However, I didn't come very far in my proof
\begin{align*}
a_{1, 1}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\widetilde{\mathbf{A}})_{i, \sigma(i)} 
&= 
a_{1, 1}\sum_{\sigma \in P_{n+1}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} 
\left(
    \frac{a_{i+1, \sigma(i+1)}\cdot a_{1, 1}- a_{1, \sigma(i+1)}\cdot a_{i+1, 1}}{a_{1, 1}}
\right)
\\[5pt] 
&= 
a_{1, 1}\sum_{\sigma \in P_{n+1}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
\prod_{i = 2}^{n+1} 
\left(
    \frac{a_{i, \sigma(i)}\cdot a_{1, 1}- a_{1, \sigma(i)}\cdot a_{i, 1}}{a_{1, 1}}
\right)
\\[5pt] 
&= 
\sum_{\sigma \in P_{n+1}}^{} \frac{\text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)}{(a_{1, 1})^{n-1}}
\prod_{i = 2}^{n+1} 
\left(
    {a_{i, \sigma(i)}\cdot a_{1, 1}- a_{1, \sigma(i)}\cdot a_{i, 1}}
\right)
\end{align*}
Could someone help me with the proof?

**Edit:** $P_{n+1}$ denotes the permutations of the elements $\{2, 3, \ldots, n+1\}$. Also, in the comments the Neville algorithm got mentioned, but I don't see the connection yet.

Comment: Related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm

Comment: @ErikSatie could you maybe elaborate? I don't immediately see the connection.

Comment: Are you trying to prove Cramer's rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#General_case)?

Comment: @Mason not really, I'm trying to proof Leibniz's rule (but not from the constructive point of view where you derive it using the properties)

Comment: @Rhi What exactly are you trying to prove? The thing about the determinant being in the denominator of the solutions sounds like Cramer's rule.

Comment: @Mason No, the determinant of the general solution (i.e. if you solve the system for $x_1$, $x_2$, ...) is given by Leibniz's rule, and this is what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: @Rhi Are you trying to prove that $\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1, \sigma(1)}\dots a_{n, \sigma(n)}$? If so, how are you defining $\det$?

Comment: @Mason Yes, but I pretend to not know the determinant yet, I only consider the denominator of the general solution.

Comment: @Rhi How can you pretend to not know the determinant, yet you know Leibniz formula for the determinant?! And what do you mean exactly by "denominator of the general solution"?

Comment: @Mason If you have a general system of $n$ linear equations and solve this system,  int the solution vector $\mathbf{x}$, every entry will have the same denominator (assuming sufficient conditions so that this denominator isn't zero). Due to observations one can conjecture the Leibniz formula for the determinant yields this denominator (hence the denominator is what we call the determinant today). So essentially I'm trying to derive the determinant in a different way.