# Proving sum/product identity without using the determinant

Tags: summation, permutations, determinant, products

I want to show that

\begin{align*}
   \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n+1}}^{} \text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)
    \prod_{i = 1}^{n+1} a_{i, \sigma(i)}
= \frac{1}{{a_{1, 1}^{n-1}}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}^{}{\text{sgn}\left(\sigma\right)} 
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} 
\left(
    a_{i+1, \sigma(i)+1}\cdot a_{1, 1}- a_{1, \sigma(i)+1}\cdot a_{i+1, 1}
\right)
.\end{align*}
However, I'm not allowed to give an argument that involves the determinant and its properties. Could someone give me a hint how to start? (I have seen a question involving the above identity [here on this platform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346690/proving-the-leibniz-formula-for-determinants)).

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, it's $\sigma(i) + 1$. What you proposed does not make much sense because $n+1 \notin S_n$